# __() with sprintf returns untranslated string

Tags: localization

I'm going through some legacy code and adding i18n functions throughout when I stumbled on a localisation snippet I found inside a `pre_get_document_title` function: (simplified)

```
$title = 'Hello World';
__( $title, 'my_text_domain' );
```

This returns the correct, translated string. It was recently pointed out to me however, that this isn't valid syntax as localisation functions should only receive a string; not a variable, nor a function return value. The recommended (and correct) syntax, as seen in numerous themes:

```
sprintf( __( '%s', 'my_text_domain' ), $title );
```

Having made this change, I find that all my titles are now still in English. i.e. nothing gets translated. All the language files are still there, all I did was modify the __() calls.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: I don't see any issues with the above code. There is smething else going on. Did you generate the language file again after you changed the __() calls?

Comment: My guess is that if you generate the .pot, .md files again, it would be fixed.

Comment: The site's been up with several locales for some time with no translation issues until this cropped up. Should I try recompiling all the .mo files again?

Comment: I suppose it may fix it, just try it if you can.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the functions being called is wrong.

With this code:

```
sprintf( __( '%s', 'my_text_domain' ), $title );
```

- You are trying to translate the string '%s' in the domain 'my_text_domain'.
- you are then replacing the translated string for '%s' (which is '%s'), by the content of the variable `$title`.
- Therefore your code is similar to `sprintf( '%s', $title);`

What you should do:

```
__( sprintf( '%s', $title ), 'my_text_domain' );
```

- `sprintf()` will return your title
- `__()` will translate the returned title

By the way, if you plan to use the title of the post only, you probably don't need to use `sprintf()` but instead:

```
__( $title, 'my_text_domain );
```